# How to make my words clickable and direct it to another HTML file?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I make it so when I click a word in my footer, it takes the user to another page that has information related to what they clicked? The help I need is how do I link HTML files appropriately and how do I make a word clickable that will take me from HTML file #1 to HTML file #2.

Do I just have to make a new file and link rel it in my first HTML page and then place the HTML name (of HTML file #2) in a href with a word?

If you are confused, look at the footer on https://gotinder.com I essentially want to be able to do something like that. 
An important note I should add is that I'm using bootstrap.

Here's a link to what my page look like https://gyazo.com/2e012e31ed40f419c702121ec42d9a8e

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- If IE use the latest rendering engine -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<!-- Set the page to the width of the device and set the zoon level -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
    <title>
        title
    </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
</head>


<body>




<div class="wrapper">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Facebook</button>
    </div>




<div class="footer">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-mg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <h4 style="color: #DB4C2C">Download</h4>
    Download for Android (Cooming Soon) <br>
    Download for iOS (Coming Soon)

</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-mg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
    <h4 style="color: #DB4C2C">Company</h4>
    Jobs (Unavailable)<br>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-mg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
    <h4 style="color: #DB4C2C">Support</h4>
    For support purposes,

</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-mg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
    <h4 style="color: #DB4C2C">Legal</h4>
    Privacy<br>Terms<br>Safety<br><a href="http://google.com" class="btn btn-default">Go to Google</a>

</div>
</div>

  </div>





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>



<!-- Problems to fix include:
- Move the Piddash logo to the left.
-->
```

then

```
html,body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  }
.wrapper {
           display:flex;
           align-items:center; 
           width:100%;
           height:100%;
           background-image: url("../img/space.jpg");
           background-repeat:no-repeat;
           background-size:cover;

     }

    .button {
      width:100px;
      margin:auto;
    }

    .footer {

padding-bottom: 50px;
padding-left: auto;
padding-right: auto;


    }

    .btn {
  margin:0 auto;
}
.row {
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.h4 {
  font-family: Arial, Sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Does a regular anchor tag not do what you need? Sounds like you're trying to do nothing more than make a regular link.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I did not understand your question but is this what you want?

```
<a href="nameoffileyouwanttolink.html">Text that will display as link<a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using backend routing and only HTML & CSS:
    `<a href="FileName.html"> Click Here</a>`

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 3 right now.. If I buy a domain and upload my code onto a domain, do I have to recode it for it to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<a href="#">Link text</a>` tag with custom styling options using a `class`
You can learn more about `HTML a tag` from [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("../img/space.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.button {
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
.footer {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
}
.btn {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.row {
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.h4 {
  font-family: Arial, Sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- If IE use the latest rendering engine -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <!-- Set the page to the width of the device and set the zoon level -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
  <title>
    title
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
</head>


<body>




  <div class="wrapper">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Facebook</button>
  </div>




  <div class="footer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-mg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <h4 style="color: #DB4C2C">Download</h4>
        <a href="#">Download for Android (Cooming Soon)</a>
        <br> <a href="#">Download for iOS (Coming Soon)</a>

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-mg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <h4 style="color: #DB4C2C">Company</h4>
        <a href="#">Jobs (Unavailable)</a>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-mg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <h4 style="color: #DB4C2C">Support</h4>
        <a href="#">For support purposes,</a>

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-mg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <h4 style="color: #DB4C2C">Legal</h4>
        <a href="#">Privacy</a>
        <br> <a href="#">Terms</a>
        <br> <a href="#">Safety</a>
        <br><a href="http://google.com" class="btn btn-default">Go to Google</a>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>





  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>



<!-- Problems to fix include:
- Move the Piddash logo to the left.
-->
```